# Is it ok to use npm's jQuery in an HTML in the old fashion way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, npm

My main goal with this is just adding jQuery to a project without having to go to the website and download the library (or use the CDN). I am new to npm and I would like to know if doing the following steps would be OK or it would pose some kind of problem in the future. I am aware that there are other methods like Webpack but I am interested in knowing if this practice is wrong.

Also, if this practice is wrong what would you recommend only to obtain a copy of jQuery for a website.

1. create a directory
2. npm install jquery@latest
3. Create index.html *(or php or whatever)*
4. Insert script like this:

   <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
5. Add some JavaScript.

Comment: `npm install jquery@latest --save` it will add the dependency to `package.json`, so that next time onward you can do `npm install` to install all the dependency along with `jQuery`

Comment: it's... "ok" in that it would work, but... i wouldn't do it that way. I would at least copy the file from the node_modules folder to a different folder. There's no reason to have the entire source of jquery in your project just to include the minified file.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee that sounds good, I could also do a git commit with the whole thing and I would still work, right? I mean that way you wouldn't have to do the `npm install`.

Comment: @KevinB that would be a good reason not to do it. Perhaps `npm install jquery@latest -g` (global) and possibly linking the file `ln -s` or copying it?

Comment: i usually copy it. a script in package.json can do it pretty easily, then you'd just need to run `npm run scriptname` to execute it.

Comment: @KevinB as I said I am new to npm, how would this work: _a script in package.json can do it pretty easily, then you'd just need to run npm run scriptname to execute it._ ?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: @loco.loop well, the purpose of `package.json` and then doing `npm install` is that so you don't need to carry all the dependency in your repo and, and managing packages via npm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is ok if you want to keep things simple and don't want to use a bundler like webpack or rollup. You will be able to version and update your jQuery package with npm.